# Android Binding JavaScript code to Android code not Working?

Tags: javascript, android, string

I have used `JavaScript` code to `android` using this one [THIS DOCUMENT](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript) but i'am  not getting `String value` why i am facing this problem ,any one have idea on this one, help me.

This is my code

```
 webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);             
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);   

    String html = " <input type='button' value='Say hello' onClick='showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')' />" +
            "<script type='text/javascript'>   function showAndroidToast(toast) { Android.showToast(toast); }</script>";     

    webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);    
    webview.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(MainActivity.this), "Android");
```

And `WebAppInterface` class like this

```
public class WebAppInterface {
Context mContext;

/** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
WebAppInterface(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

/** Show a toast from the web page */
@JavascriptInterface
public void showToast(String toast) {
    Log.i(" ", " " + toast);
    Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part does not seem very viable:

```
'showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')'
```

Your quotes will not be closed correctly. Use escaped double quotes instead for the outer:

```
\"showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')\"
```

Comment: in that tutorial i will see this one  `Caution: If you've set your targetSdkVersion to 17 or higher,` is it possible only 17 or highet what about lower versions

Comment: @NagarjunaReddy This is basically a subject of new question. However: you can add javascript interfaces for API 8 and above. However it will not be using the annotation -it will go to ordinary class